# Qml: Adding content dynamically to a SequentialAnimation

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I have an Qml component with a `SequentialAnimation` containing a static sequence of `PropertyAction` components:

```
SequentialAnimation {
  id: anim
  running: true

  PropertyAction { target: icon; property: "iconid"; value: propStore.anim1 }
  PropertyAction { target: icon; property: "iconid"; value: propStore.anim2 }
  PropertyAction { target: icon; property: "iconid"; value: propStore.anim3 }
}
```

This accomplishes that a specific icon is animated. However now I'd like to make it a little bit dynamic by building the sequence dynamically. The reason is that the `propStore` isn't under my control, and users adding new images to the animation sequence require me to make changes to the Qml :(

How should I go about doing this?

My first thought was to dynamically add components to `anim.animations`, but that doesn't work (it seems to be a read-only property of `SequentialAnimation`.)

My next thought was to add a `ListModel` to the outer component, and in its `Component.onCompleted` slot I append objects of the shape `{ image: "animN" }` (I get the "animN" strings using introspection on `propStore`.)  Then I use the `ListModel` to populate a `Repeater`.  However, the `SequentialAnimation` doesn't seem to accept a `Repeater` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't append directly to anim.animations, but you can reaffect it to a new value. Build a JS array from anim.animation, append a dynamically created animation to it, then reaffect it to anim.animations.

Here's a simple example.

```
Component
{
    id: component
    SequentialAnimation
    {
        id: seq
        property string color
        PropertyAction {target: rect; property: "color"; value: seq.color}
        PauseAnimation { duration: 500 }
    }
}

function addAnim(color)
{
    var listAnim = []
    for(var i=0; i<anim.animations.length; i++)
        listAnim.push(anim.animations[i])
    var temp = component.createObject(root, {"color":color})
    listAnim.push(temp)
    anim.animations = listAnim
}

    Rectangle
{
    id: rect
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: row.top
    anchors.margins: 40
    border.width: 1

    SequentialAnimation
    {
        id: anim
    }
}

Row
{
    id: row
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 50
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    spacing: 10

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Play")
        onClicked: anim.start()
    }
    Repeater
    {
        model: ["red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Add %1").arg(modelData[0])
            onClicked: addAnim(modelData)
        }
    }
}
```