# Array of animations for `SequentialAnimation`

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to have an array of animations which allow a large number of animations to be run together?

Consider the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: mywindow
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 100; height: 100
        color: "red"

        SequentialAnimation {
            running: true
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; to: 150; duration: 1000 }
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "y"; to: 150; duration: 1000 }
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; to: 250; duration: 1000 }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code runs three animations one after another. A rectangle moves right, down and then right again. However, is it possible to create a large *array* of such animations under `SequentialAnimation`, and then play them one after another? This will allow me to design more complex motions for that rectangle.

Could someone give an rewrite the example above where the three number animations above are lumped/zipped into an "arrayAnimation" (assuming there is such a thing)

Comment: An example where the three number animations above are lumped/zipped into an "arrayAnimation" (assuming there is such a thing)

Comment: What do you mean by "arrayAnimation"?

Comment: Do you want a SequentialAnimation that has SequentialAnimation inside instead of NumberAnimation?

Comment: You could show a pseudocode of what you want, your question is not clear.

Comment: I also don't understand what exactly you want to do but using [ParallelAnimation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-parallelanimation.html) and [SequentialAnimation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-sequentialanimation.html) you can create complicated animation as you want

Comment: is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547894/qml-adding-content-dynamically-to-a-sequentialanimation what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I wanted a `SequentialAnimation` whose animation-elements could be updated dynamically at run-time.